# Android emulator issues on Mountain Lion

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am facing a lot of issues with Mountain Lion and Android Emulator. Not only does it show up in weird form factor, which I am sure is happening because of scaling issues. It crashes abruptly. Infact, the emulator has not run for me in last month or so. I know some folks have suggested running mac on native screen resolution. But the mac becomes useless on such small form factor. Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Actually my bad, there is this tool, goes by the name RDM which allows you to change OSX resolution to non-scaled factors (this is important) because if you use HiDPI it will crash. Using this my emulator comes up. I still dont know how stable it is.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed in the BETA version of the r21 tools: http://tools.android.com/preview-channel

Keep in mind this is beta, so there may be other issues with the tools.